# reading rep file in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to read a ".rep" file in VBA, here's the code I'm using:

```
FileNum = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input As #FileNum

Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
LineItems = Split(DataLine, vbTab)
```

except that after the last code line, I have all of the file in "LineItems" (it becomes an array with 15K cells) and not just the first row (when I open the same file through Excel - I see it in the correct lines)

does anyone have an idea how to read it line-by-line?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try `vbNewline` instead?

```
LineItems = Split(DataLine, vbNewLine)
```

or this:

```
LineItems = Split(DataLine, vbCrLf)
```

**Edit1:** Ok try this then:

```
Dim LineItems() As String    

Open Filename For Input As #Filenum
LineItems() = Split(Input$(LOF(Filenum), #Filenum), vbNewLine)
Close #Filenum
```

Comment: it returns all of the file in one cell - LineItems(0)

Comment: How about `vbCrLf`? as seen in my edit? If it parses correctly in excel, then it must have something for per row delimiter.

Comment: It does the same as "vbNewLine"

Comment: Try using `vbLf` as the delimiter.